# How to run multiple commands from ant exec task

Tags: ant, dos

I want to run two dos commands from Ant exec task.

I have tried below code

```
<exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" executable="cmd" failonerror="true" output="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}\BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" resultproperty="execrc">
                    <arg value="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus}"/>
                    <arg value="/c Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
                </exec>
```

but it executes only first command and skips second.
I am trying this on windows OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Simply chaining the commands.

```
<exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" executable="cmd" failonerror="true" output="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}\BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" resultproperty="execrc">
    <arg value="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus} &amp; Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier, but gives me an error of unknown character "&"

Comment: I script above works. But with entity masked ampersand

Comment: I came here with the same question, and this answer it perfectly. I first tried `&` but ANT was complaining about that character, but `&amp;` does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to run two commands in a single `<exec>` task? Instead, just use a second `<exec>` task. You can include both in a single target:

```
 <target name="execute.this">
     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus}"/>

     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
     </exec>
```

Or better yet, just use the `<echo>` task:

```
     <echo message="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus}"/>
     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" 
         failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
     </exec>
```

If you need the output of the `echo` task in the same file, you can use the `file` parameter in the `echo` command, and the `append` parameter in the `exec` task.