# How to run multiple commands with arguments from single Ant exec task

Tags: ant

On windows, I am trying to execute two commands (.cmd and .exe) later requiring parameters,in one exec() task. This is to avoid using two shell ,however only first command is getting executed.

Following is the Ant snippet

```
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.7\server\bin\">
            <arg value="/c mqsiprofile.cmd &amp; C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.7\server\bin\mqsideploy.exe" />
            <arg value="IIBNODE1" />
            <arg value="-e" />
            <arg value="default" />
            <arg value="-a" />
            <arg value="${bar.name}" />
        </exec>
```

I also ran it without &amp and replacing "PROGRA~1" with "Program Files", still the same issue. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can include both in a single target:

```
<target name="execute.this">
     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus}"/>

     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
     </exec>
```

Or better yet, just use the `<echo>` task:

```
<echo message="/c echo Download Status is ${DownloadStatus}"/>
     <exec dir="${testworkspace}\${moduleName}" 
         executable="cmd" 
         failonerror="true" 
         output="${testworkspace}/${moduleName}/BuildConsole_TC${tc_num}.log" 
         resultproperty="execrc">
         <arg value="/c Load.bat ${moduleName} ${Intapp} ${CcvStatus}"/>
     </exec>
```

If you need the output of the `echo` task in the same file, you can use the file parameter in the `echo` command, and the append parameter in the `exec` task.

Ref: [How to run multiple commands from ant exec task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401895/how-to-run-multiple-commands-from-ant-exec-task)